# Shipping rates based on product type and quantity?

Tags: shipping

I have a requirement where I have to calculate shipping rates based on many conditions, below will impact the rates:

- Summer or Winter
- Different Containers (4 containers)
- Different types of products (6 types)
- Combinations of products in cart (qty based)

So let's see an example,
If below products have been added to cart,

```
(2 qty) Product Type 1 - Container 1 - Type 1 - Summer
(1 qty) Product Type 2 - Container 2 - Type 1 - Summer
```

then rates will come based on that combination.

It's hard to explain, but I want to know how to startoff with such type of product-based shipping calculations.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create a new shipping method. [This should help you do that.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).
Then all you need to do is to calculate the cost in the method `collectRates` of your new module. You have access to the products in the cart in that method using `$request->getAllItems()`.

```
$price = 0;
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item){
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    //do something with $item or $product
    //$price += 30;//add an amount to the total price
}
```

After calculating the total price just replace the line in the example:

```
$method->setPrice($rMethod['amount']+$handling);
```

with

```
$method->setPrice($price);
```

Comment: @MagExt did you tried ?