# Magento Shipping the same for certain quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, quantity

I would like to make it so that a certain quantity of a product has the same exact shipping price and when the quantity goes over the threshold, the shipping price doubles.

**For example**, for product X, the shipping price is Y for quantities 1-12. For 13-24, the shipping price is Yx2, for 25-36, it's Yx3 and so on.

The reason for this is the manufacturer considers anything in a box of 12 (whether it actually has 12 or not in there) is a certain "weight" (the weight is how much it would be if it was 12 products, even if there is less than 12 products in there).

To make thing a little more difficult, the shipping is not a flat rate throughout the website. Each product has a different weight and needs to be calculated differently from one another.

**I hope this makes sense. It's very hard to explain over text. I'm new to Magento so I have no idea how to start looking for a solution.**

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7564/shipping-rates-based-on-product-type-and-quantity

Answer (score 0):

Create your own shipping method following [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).
in the `collectRates` of your module you need to put the logic for calculating the shipping price.

You can access the items in the shopping cart like this:

```
$request->getAllItems();
```

where `$request` is the parameter you receive for the `collectRates` method.

You can do something like this (untested):

```
$price = 0;
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
    //exclude duplicate items from the configurable products
    if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
       continue;
    }
    $qty = $item->getQty();
    $factor = (int)(($qty - 1) / 12) + 1; //this should give you the correct number of boxes but please check again
    $productShippingPrice = include logic here to determine the shipping price for one product or one box.
    //add shipping price to total
    $price += $productShippingPrice * $factor;

}
//add the price to the shipping method. See who `$method` is in the tutorial
$method->setPrice($price);
```

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll take a look at this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link:
https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024848/Create+a+Shipping+Method+Module

It may solve your issue.