# what shipping method or extension to use?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I've searched online for 3 days but couldnt find a solution at all... hope someone can give me a solution....

The idea is quite simple. I offer free shipping to lower 48 states. 
and charge extra shipping to PR, AK, and Hawaii, also Canada. 
Simple right ??

the tricky part is, I charge different shipping fee depend on the item and locations.

for example, we charge $7 to ship to PR, AK, HI/$20 to ship to Canada for product A.
and charge $11 to ship to PR, AK, HI, $30 to Canada for product B and so on..

actually it can be done with table rate (weight vs destination)..
but the problem is all items must ship separately.

so if a customer from PR bought two product A, shipping would be $7x2
if bought one product A and one product B, shipping would be $7 + $11
and shipping would be $33 if customer from PR bought three of product B.

is there anyway I can accomplish this? 
or an extension can do the job? Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7565/45103 this will be the helpful to you to start

Comment: I am working on something similar using this as a guide, http://addoa.com/blog/how-restrict-free-shipping-magento

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [Owebia Advanced Shipping module for Magento 1](https://en.store.owebia.com/magento1-module-shipping-free.html). It allows you to create formulas for the shipping rates which sounds perfect for your situation.

You can setup rules for the different products, locations and reference the quantity of items in the basket and product type. Your system seems very complicated so I don't think I would have the time to work out the formulas involved (maybe later if I have some time).

The plugin documentation is available [here](https://owebia.com/os2/en/doc)